# ffmpeg: make a copy from a decoded frame (AVFrame)

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, video-processing

I want to make a backup frame (AVFrame) from a special frame(let's say *pic*). So, I have written

```
 AVFrame* bkf = avcodec_alloc_frame();
 memcpy(bkf,pic,sizeof(AVFrame));
 bkf->extended_data = pic->extended_data;
 bkf->linesize[0]   = pic->linesize[0];
 memcpy(bkf->data, pic->data, sizeof(pic->data));
 bkf->reordered_opaque = pic->reordered_opaque;
 bkf->sample_rate    = pic->sample_rate;
 bkf->channel_layout = pic->channel_layout;
 bkf->pkt_pts = pic->pkt_pts;
 bkf->pkt_pos = pic->pkt_pos;
 bkf->width = pic->width;
 bkf->format =  pic ->format;
```

to copy *pic*  to *bkf*. But after running, I saw a lot of distortion. any idea how to make a correct copy from a decoded frame?

Answer (score 7):

Use [av_frame_copy](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__frame.html#gaec4e92f6e1e75ffaf76e07586fb0c9ed)(bkf, pic) after allocating bkf with AVFrame *bkf = [av_frame_alloc](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__frame.html#gac700017c5270c79c1e1befdeeb008b2f)().

Comment: "This function only copies the frame data (i.e. the contents of the data / extended data arrays), not any other properties."

Comment: See `av_frame_copy_props()` for that.