# Copying a decoded ffmpeg AVFrame

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

I've been trying to copy a AVFrame just like what was answered in [ffmpeg: make a copy from a decoded frame (AVFrame)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083278/ffmpeg-make-a-copy-from-a-decoded-frame-avframe). However but I can't seem to get it to get a positive return code from av_frame_copy().

Here is basically what I'm doing:

```
AVFrame *copyFrame = NULL;
copyFrame = av_frame_alloc();

int return_code = av_frame_copy(copyFrame, originalFrame);
if(return_code < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "av_frame_copy failed with return code %d\n", return_code);
    return(1);
}
```

If it helps, the return code I get from av_frame_copy is -22.

Comment: Error -22 seems to mean that one of your arguments in invalid, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205017/ffmpeg-avcodec-open2-returns-22-if-i-change-my-speaker-configuration/26205126#26205126)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you read the documentation for [`av_frame_copy`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__frame.html#gaec4e92f6e1e75ffaf76e07586fb0c9ed), it says "This function does not allocate anything, dst must be already initialized and allocated with the same parameters as src."

[`av_frame_alloc`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__frame.html#gac700017c5270c79c1e1befdeeb008b2f) doesn't do anything other than allocate the `AVFrame` struct and initialize it to some default values. Most importantly, it doesn't allocate buffers for the frame data or prepare the frame to be used. `av_frame_copy` is failing because the destination frame doesn't have the correct pixel format set or buffers allocated.

If you want to clone a frame (by incrementing its reference counter, not creating a deep copy) you can use [`av_frame_clone`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__frame.html#ga46d6d32f6482a3e9c19203db5877105b) or [`av_frame_ref`](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__frame.html#ga88b0ecbc4eb3453eef3fbefa3bddeb7c).

If you want to move the frame you can use [`av_frame_move_ref`](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__frame.html#ga709e62bc2917ffd84c5c0f4e1dfc48f7).

But you probably want to do a proper deep copy. In that case, you can look at the source code of the [`av_frame_make_writable`](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__frame.html#gadd5417c06f5a6b419b0dbd8f0ff363fd). This function makes a deep copy of the frame if it isn't writeable, so we can use the same logic to make a deep copy of the frame here:

```
AVFrame *copyFrame = av_frame_alloc();
copyFrame->format = frame->format;
copyFrame->width = frame->width;
copyFrame->height = frame->height;
copyFrame->channels = frame->channels;
copyFrame->channel_layout = frame->channel_layout;
copyFrame->nb_samples = frame->nb_samples;
av_frame_get_buffer(copyFrame, 32);
av_frame_copy(copyFrame, frame);
av_frame_copy_props(copyFrame, frame);
```

Note that I haven't checked for errors in the functions I've called. You should do that in your real code. I omitted it here for brevity.

Comment: Thanks for this. I read the documentation but kept getting stuck on how to use av_frame_get_buffer(). I've been mainly working with scripting languages but I'm currently working hard to learn C. Thank you for your patience. It was the "int align" parameter that was throwing me off because I had no idea what align was supposed to be.

Comment: Glad it was helpful! The alignment depends on what you're doing, though an alignment of 32 is pretty safe and should work for pretty much anything you're doing. Some CPU instructions, especially advanced SIMD instructions used in optimized routines, require a specific alignment. You might be able to get away with an alignment of 1, but unless you know what you're doing with the alignment I'd recommend using 32. The [`AVFrame.linesize`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVFrame.html#aa52bfc6605f6a3059a0c3226cc0f6567) documentation has a few more details.

Answer (score 1):

I had AVFrame * on GPU. This worked for me:

```
int ret;
AVFrame *dst;
dst = av_frame_alloc();

memcpy(dst,src,sizeof(AVFrame));

dst->format         = src->format;
dst->width          = src->width;
dst->height         = src->height;
dst->channels       = src->channels;
dst->channel_layout = src->channel_layout;
dst->nb_samples     = src->nb_samples;
dst->extended_data  = src->extended_data;

memcpy(dst->data, src->data, sizeof(src->data));

ret = av_frame_copy_props(dst, src);

if (ret < 0) { av_frame_unref(dst);}
```

Comment: I dont think this will work stably because the data in dst is not allocated and is not deep copied. `memcpy(dst->data, src->data, sizeof(src->data));` copies only the data pointer.

Comment: In this way, dst->data == src->data

Answer (score 0):

```
        AVFrame *copyFrame = new AVFrame;
        copyFrame = av_frame_alloc();
        *copyFrame = *inAVFrame;
        if (int iRet = av_frame_copy(copyFrame, inAVFrame) == 0) {
            //av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Ok");
        } else {
            //av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Error: %s\n", AV_err2str(iRet));
        }
```